# Why is instance variable not getting recognized

Tags: python

I have the following class in Python.

```
import os,ConfigParser

class WebPageTestConfigUtils:

    def __init__(self, configParser=None, configFilePath=None):
        self.configParser = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
        self.configFilePath = (os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'webPageTestConfig.cfg'))

    def initializeConfig(self):
        configParser.read(configFilePath)
        return configParser

    def getConfigValue(self,key):
        return configParser.get('WPTConfig', key)

def main():
webPageTestConfigUtils = WebPageTestConfigUtils()
webPageTestConfigUtils.initializeConfig()
webPageTestConfigUtils.getConfigValue('testStatus')

if  __name__ =='__main__':
main()
```

Upon execution . This gives me the error.

`NameError: global name 'configParser' is not defined`.

Why is python not able to recognize the instance variable here.
~
~

Comment: You don't need extra `(` `)` around `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'webPageTestConfig.cfg')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's expected. In your code, python will not be able to access class members without self. Here is the correct code:

```
def initializeConfig(self):
    self.configParser.read(self.configFilePath)
    return self.configParser

def getConfigValue(self,key):
    return self.configParser.get('WPTConfig', key)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are defining

```
...
self.configParser = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
...
```

And accessing using

```
...
configParser.read(configFilePath)
...
```

You have to access as `self.configParser`.